# Trying to take the max and min values out of a user input and displaying them in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, max, min, ctrl

OK thanks so now the code can find the word in the string array but now I need to get the most positive word from the user input and the most negative word from the user input. So if I plug in dreadful zone, dreadful is 1.25 and zone is 2.66, so dreadful is the most negative word and zone is the most positive word but how the code is set up I don't know how to keep track of those values then make sure that it can print out the correct word as the most positive and the word as the post negative. So the average of the user input is printed. I tried doing parallel arrays but I want to avoid those. The other issues are being able to take multiple inputs from the user until they use the keys ctrl z or ctrl d. (I was told they are part of Eclipse but I have no idea how to use them.)
Thank you for any suggestions on how to proceed.

Output:

```
Please type one line of review and when you are done press either Ctr D or Ctr Z
dreadful zone
dreadful zone
The average is negative at 1.9583333333333333
Incomplete assignment
```

```
public class MovieReviewSentimentAnalysis {

    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // TODO: complete me

       //make own arrays to pass by value
       //movieReviewComments = the text
       String[] movieReviewComments = new String[8529];
       //movieReviewScores = numeric values, avoid lit. values 
       int[] movieReviewScores = new int[8529];

       String userComment = "";

MovieReviewReader.readMovieReviews("movie_reviews.txt", movieReviewComments, movieReviewScores); //string, string array, and int array

       System.out.println("Please type one line of review and when you are done press either Ctr D or Ctr Z");
       userComment = userInput.nextLine();
       System.out.println(userComment);




//     String[] words = userComment.split("\\s+");
       String[] words2  = userComment.split("[\\W]"); //splits at "\W", or non-word characters
       double singularUserWordTotal = 0;
       double wordTotal = 0;
       double totalSumOfUserCommentWords = 0;
       double highestWordScore = 20;

       double lowestWordScoreTotal = 0;

       int locationOfWordInUserInput = 0;

       String userInputWord = "";
//     int itemCount = words.length;
       for (int i = 0; i < words2.length; i++)
       {
           userInputWord = words2[i];
           singularUserWordTotal = wordCount(userInputWord, movieReviewComments, movieReviewScores);
           wordTotal += singularUserWordTotal;
           totalSumOfUserCommentWords = wordTotal / words2.length;

//         locationOfWordInUserInput = i;
//         if(singularUserWordTotal > highestWordScore)
//         {
//             singularUserWordTotal = highestWordScore;
//         }
//         if(singularUserWordTotal < highestWordScore)
//         {
//             singularUserWordTotal = highestWordScore;
//             lowestWordScoreTotal = singularUserWordTotal;
//         }

       }

       displayScores(totalSumOfUserCommentWords);


//     System.out.println(reviewFile);
       System.out.println("Incomplete assignment");

       userInput.close();
   }

   public static double wordCount(String userInputWord, String[] movieReviewComments, int[] movieReviewScores)
   {
       double storeScore = 0;
       double totalSumOfReviewScores = 0;
       double numOfTimesWordAppears = 0;

       for (int i=0; i < (movieReviewComments.length); i++)
       {
           if (movieReviewComments[i].contains(userInputWord))
               //PUNCTUATION IS A PROBLEM (if it's at the end of the user input then it's fine though)
           {
               storeScore = movieReviewScores[i];
               totalSumOfReviewScores += storeScore;

               numOfTimesWordAppears++;

               //System.out.println("Found");

              //What if the word doesn't appear in the text file?????

           }else if (!movieReviewComments[i].contains(userInputWord))
                   {
                    numOfTimesWordAppears += 0;
                   }
//         else
//            System.out.println("You dun goofed"); //delete after fixing problem
       }
       double wordScoreAverage = totalSumOfReviewScores / numOfTimesWordAppears;
       return wordScoreAverage;
   }

   public static double displayScores(double userCommentTotal)
   {
       if(userCommentTotal > 2.01)
       {
           System.out.println("The average is positive at " + userCommentTotal);
       }else if(userCommentTotal < 2.01 && userCommentTotal > 1.99)
       {
           System.out.println("The average is neutral at " + userCommentTotal);
       }else
           System.out.println("The average is negative at " + userCommentTotal);

       return userCommentTotal;
   }
```

Comment: Use a Two Dimensional Array. Allow the first column of the Array hold the Word and the second column of the Array hold the word numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use HashMap for this:

```
Map<String,Integer> h = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
h.put(word,word_score);
//get word score
int score = h.get(word)
```